# ActiveX control '{XXX-XXX}' is not registered in this computer. Register the control and try again

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

While migration of old application, which built on VC6.0 framework. I am getting below error message when I tried to open Dialog box from Resource View windows.

> The ActiveX control 6262D3A0-531B-11CF-91F6-C2863C338E30', is not registered on this computer. Register the control and try again.

Please suggest step to open the dialog. (Dialog having ActiveX control, which is absolute in latest window OS i.e. Window 10/11)

I tried to find ActiveX components on MS site, but no luck.

Comment: The ActiveX control
6262D3A0-531B-11CF-91F6-C2863C338E30', is not registered
on this computer.
Register the control and try again.

Comment: Do you know what active-x component that is?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I installed the 64-bit version of Visual Studio, but the ActiveX controls I was trying to load were built for 32-bit.  There are two options to fix this:

1. Install the 32-bit version of Visual Studio and use that.
2. Rebuild the ActiveX control for 64-bit and register that .ocx.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities come to mind after you have ruled out that this is a standard Microsoft component:

- It might be that this is a 3rd party component someone once bought. Look for an .ocx that might be present in the project files in a 3rd party folder. It could help, if you disclose the relevant lines in the resource file, so people have the chance to identify the component and with some luck tell you where you could get it.
- There is a chance that this is a custom-made component: Look for a subproject and build it.

In any case register the component before use, for example `regsvr32.exe path\to\your\component\the_comp.ocx`. (On a 64-bit Windows, you might want to use `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe`, suppose this is a x86 project.)